# MongoInternalException while inserting into mongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I was entering data into mongodb but suddenly encountered with this error.Don't know how to fix this.Is this due to maximum size exceeded?.If no then why I am getting this error?.Anyone know how to fix this? Below is the error which I encountered

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: DBObject of size 163745644 is over Max BSON size 16777216
```

I know my dataset is large...but is there any other solution??

Answer (score 3):

the document you are trying to insert is exceeding the max BSON document size ie *16 MB*

Here is the reference documentation : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB provides the **[GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/)** API.

> The mongofiles utility makes it possible to manipulate files stored in
>   your MongoDB instance in GridFS objects from the command line. It is
>   particularly useful as it provides an interface between objects stored
>   in your file system and GridFS.

Ref : [MongoFiles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/#bin.mongofiles)

Comment: @rahulroc....thanks for your reply...but my data is so large ......so somehow i had to insert it....wat to do minimise the data size or is there any other way??

Answer (score 2):

For inserting an document of size greater than 16MB you need to use GRIDFS by MongoDB. GridFS is an abstraction layer on mongoDB which divide data in chunks (by default 255K ). As you are using java, its simple to use with java driver too. I am inserting an elasticsearch jar(of size 20mb) in mongoDB. Sample code :

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("testDB");

    String newFileName = "elasticsearch-Jar";
    File imageFile = new  File("/home/impadmin/elasticsearch-1.4.2.tar.gz");

    GridFS gfs = new GridFS(db);

    //Insertion  
    GridFSInputFile inputFile = gfs.createFile(imageFile);

    inputFile.setFilename(newFileName);
    inputFile.put("name", "devender");
    inputFile.put("age", 23);
    inputFile.save();

    //Fetch back 
    GridFSDBFile outputFile = gfs.findOne(newFileName);
```

Find out more [here](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-save-image-example/).

If you want to insert directly using mongoclient you will use mongofiles as mentioned in other answer.

Hope that helps.....:)